# Bootstrap touch/click sensivity, preventing touch events during scroll

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, touch

Bootstrap is too sensitive regarding the click/touch events on mobile devices. When you try to scrool a page and accidentaly touching a clickable element, it immediately fires the element and clicking it rather than scroll.

Do you know how can solve it?

Comment: did you solve that problem?

Comment: I did but actually I don't remember how :( It may be solved buy a bootstrap update